# Current feature pack which is installed in WCS

Tags: websphere-7

Is there a way to find out the current installed feature pack and fix pack version in WCS?

The versionInfo.bat does not give me the sufficient information related to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versionInfo.bat should tell you that: 
in the section Installed Products you should see something like this:

```
Installed Products
----------------------
Name IBM Websphere Commerce 
ID 7.0.0.6
Build Level wc.toolkit.be
(...)
```

- the 4th number of id is the fix pack number in this case is FixPack 6

if you have installed Feature pack you should see another Installed Product section below:

```
Installed Product
------------------
Name IBM Websphere Commerce
Version 5.0.0.0
ID wc.fep5
(...)
```

- that is the 5th Feature pack installed

If you have none of this that means that you have no fix or feature pack installed

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the versions of installed packages using

Start->All Programs-> IBM Installation Manager->View Installed Packages.

or

using this file

C:\ {IBM RAD Installed Path}\IBM\Installation Manager\installed.xml